# Is there a way of scraping content from Facebook groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

I'd like to get the content from a facebook group since there is a lot of valuable information in there. So is there way, hack or function that you could accomplish this with?

Comment: whay do you mean by "the content"?
if you're talking about the feed of the groups, you can accomplish this with the Graph API, (if your user has the permissions to do it on the specific group)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, do an HTTP POST to the Graph API `/{groupId}` with your access code and you will get information programmatically. See:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Comment: did you mean 'HTTP GET'?